# How to solve: Can't copy file '[Content_Types].xml' to Visual Studio 2022 Extension directory. Please close all Visual Studio instances

Tags: visual-studio

**1.Explaination**

I have visual studio 2022 and i want to install the .Net Reactor extension.

The error i get is as below:

*Can't copy file '[Content_Types].xml' to Visual Studio 2022 Extension directory. Please close all Visual Studio instances.*

Even when i fully close visual studio, by closing all the tasks in the Task manager, and try to install, the error is the same.

**2.Question**

What is the problem?

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an undeleted value on the registry, but i have not been able to solve it yet.

But, as a workaround to this problem, you can directly copy the file:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Eziriz.NET Reactor\VSPackage\17\ [Content_Types].xml

to

C:\Users%CurrentUser%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_17555130\Extensions

This enables .Net Reactor inside VIsual Studio 2022.

P.S.
The directory : 17.0_17555130
is created for the version 17.9.5
if you have a newer or older version, then you will have a different directory name.